# SQL - Can sub-query have a different condition from main query?

Tags: sql

I want to return a count value in the resultset. This count value uses a different condition from the main query. Is it possible to acheive this using sub-query i.e., in a single query?

```
SELECT ID, DESC, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.ID=ID AND STATUS_ID=2) 
COUNT FROM TABLE1 WHERE STATUS_ID=6
```

Comment: Have you tried this query? Is it works as you expect?

Comment: Try using aliases to distinguish between the main query and the sub-query fields.

Comment: I tried the query. The count value is not returned as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

However, if you use the same table more than once in a query / subquery, you should use different aliases, to be clear what exactly you are selecting or comparing

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.DESC, 
  ( SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM TABLE1 t2
    WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID AND t2.STATUS_ID=2) COUNT 
FROM TABLE1 t1
WHERE t1.STATUS_ID=6
```

Comment: Yes. This helps. I am able to get back the count properly.